# How to find the pattern between starting and corresponding ending bracket using shell script

Tags: linux, unix, grep, sh

I have a file which contains the below pattern

```
CREATE TABLE hello
(
a string CHARACTER SET ISO88591 NO
DEFAULT -- NOT NULL
, b int NO DEFAULT -- NOT NULL
, c string NO DEFAULT -- NOT NULL
, d string CHARACTER SET ISO88591 DEFAULT
NULL
, e string CHARACTER SET ISO88591 DEFAULT
NULL
, f string CHARACTER SET ISO88591 DEFAULT
NULL
, CONSTRAINT xyz(hello)
, CONSTRAINT xyz CHECK
(hello how r u)
)
```

The output should be

```
a string
, b int 
, c string 
, d string 
, e string 
, f string
```

I tried the below commands to extract the pattern b/w brackets but since there are inner brackets its not able to find the match. I need to find all the text b/w the 1st bracket and last bracket.

```
cat file.txt | grep -i '(.*)'
 awk '/(.*)/' file.txt
```

Appreciate any help in this regard

Comment: This doesn't work because grep works line-based. Google for a solution with awk. You will find plenty here on stackoverflow, too.

Comment: why `CONSTRAINT` should not be matched?

Comment: For that data and that output you can use this: `grep -o "^.*\(string\|int\)" file`. If you want to go deeper into parsing those parenthesis I'd recommend awk.

Comment: Thanks...I am trying using awk also

Comment: I think you want to do much more than just pick the parts of the file within parenthesis, but you're not telling what are the rules on what to keep. Unless you mean you want to parse that according to the syntax of some variant of SQL, and print out just certain tokens. In which case the answer is probably something like lex+yacc.

Answer (score -1):

Parsing SQL is always a messy business.  Ideally you'd use an SQL parser, but they're basically made of unobtanium.  And so we hack.  Something like the following would work in awk:

```
/^[(]/ {
    parsing = 1
    next;
}

/^[)]/ {
    parsing = 0
}

parsing == 0 {
    next
}

/string|int/ {
    name = $1
    type = $2
}

/^,.+string|int/ {
    name = $2
    type = $3
}

{ print name, type }
```

Comment: So what?  SO isn't a free programming service, and his single example input doesn't cover all cases.  A working script would break on other valid SQL.  "Something like" my answer will work.  It shows a valid approach to the question asked using a technology the OP is evidently unfamiliar with.  To make it work with his entire input, he'll have to RTFM regardless.